# AngularJS: External Modal Templates

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I read [Agularjs - include external html file into modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114745/agularjs-include-external-html-file-into-modals), but it didn't include much code or explanation and just pointed to docs that I've read.  So, I will go into more detail.

I have a main html file for a SPA (Single Page Application).  I want to use modals for more detailed views.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>

<!-- want this to be in a separate html file -->

<div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- -->

</body>
</html>
```

And my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap.modal"]);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.showModal = true;
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $scope.showModal = false;
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.showModal = false;
  };

});
```

What would I need to add to `app.js` in order for it to be able to display external html files as modals on my main html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LhO3BVGY3owITLUMIRIh?p=preview)** so as to explain it better

To open the modal defined in a dedicated html template :

**1. The following is declared in the controller responsible for the button opening the modal :**

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalTemplate.html',
  controller: 'MyModalController'
});
```

**2. This is in the controller of the modal :**

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

See also **[ui bootstrap doc](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)**

Comment: Thanks for that code.  It was very useful.  However, I am now getting an error `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`  Do I need to run it on a web server or something?

Comment: Exactly, you need to run your app from a web server as angular fetches a template with an ajax request.

Comment: That's slightly annoying.  Is it possible to implement modals without a web server?

Comment: You have a few alternatives here. One of them is to place the templates at the end of the body in a tag `<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateName.html">...</script>`. But your are bloating the home page. Other alternative would be to customize your browser to not look that much at security, but that makes it more vulnerable. I don't suggest you any of these two alternatives. I do however suggest you to run your app through a server. First, it is really simple, and after all, you are developping a web app.

Comment: In Eclipse, when you run it on a server and try to view it in the Eclipse browser, nothing happens when you click the button to view the modal.  I had to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/ModalTest/` in Chrome, and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Please take look the documentation carefully [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

You can do something like this with templateUrl

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```