# ui-bootstrap is not wokring with angular

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular version-1.3.6 and using ui-bootstrap version-0.14.3, but it is showing me error. I have also tried ui-bootstrap version-0.10.3, version-0.12.3 etc, but no version is working.

I am using the below HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $ctrl.selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ $ctrl.selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>

    <div class="modal-parent">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the below Javascript:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

and it is showing me error:

[image]

When i changing the script to below, it starts working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

I am not able to resolve this conflict, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from these lines of code

```
ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
```

I'd guess you are trying to use properties that were added to `uib-modal` **AFTER** version 0.14.3, that's why your code works for version 2.5.0.

Either keep using 2.5.0 with a newer Angular or refactor your code using [these docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.3/#/modal).

Comment: i can not change the angular version, and 2.5 is not compatible with 1.3.6

Comment: so i guess you copied the code from the 2.5.0 docs, use the code from docs of version 0.14.3 instead, i gave to link in the answer

Comment: yea i changed it already to version 0.14.3 and using tpls version of the js, but i am getting error when i am trying to open the popup `"/template/modal/window.html 404 (Not Found)"`

Comment: you are defining your modal template as an embedded script (<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">), your `templateUrl` is `'myModalContent.html'`

Comment: what i am doing wrong, can you please describe a little bit more, and also if i want to remove the embedded script and put it in a separate file what should i do.

Comment: take all the HTML inside the `<script>` tag (the 3 divs), place them inside a separate html file, and provide the path to `templateUrl`.
look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597903/1410465

Comment: on my local when i am trying to open the ui -bootstrap-modal it is looking for /template/modal/backdrop.html and /template/modal/window.html, it is not using the cached templates in the *.tpls.js file.

Comment: it is not automatically using the tpls cached templates.